# How get intent data from filter? (IntentFilter Mono for Android)

Tags: android, mono, xamarin.android

I creating an intent filter for url as some urls but i do not know how get data when view lunching, i search forum, xamarin site and google andorid dev. in android sample code it use:

```
Get the intent that started this activity
Intent intent = getIntent();
Uri data = intent.getData();
```

but in mono for android i can not find such method i test using Intent.HasExtra(Intent.ExtraText).ToString() but always it return "False"

```
[Activity(Label = "View App")]
[IntentFilter(new[] { Intent.ActionView }, 
Categories = new[] { Intent.CategoryDefault, Intent.CategoryBrowsable }, 
DataHost = "search", DataScheme = "market", Priority = 100)]
public class ViewApp : Activity
{
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
        base.OnCreate(bundle);
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.ViewApp);
        TextView mainText = FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.mainText);

        mainText.Text = Intent.HasExtra(Intent.ExtraText).ToString() + "\r\n";
        mainText.Text += Intent.HasExtra(Intent.ExtraStream).ToString() + "\r\n";
    }
}
```

android lunch my activity but i can not find how get data from intent filter like original Uri data in android any help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Setters/Getters in Java (`setFoo()` / `getFoo()`) are exposed in Mono for Android as properties, in order to stick with C# styles.

As such, `getIntent().getData()` in Java is exposed as [`Intent`](http://androidapi.xamarin.com/?link=P%3aAndroid.App.Activity.Intent)`.`[`Data`](http://androidapi.xamarin.com/?link=P%3aAndroid.Content.Intent.Data) in Mono for Android.